# "_Problem Loading Widget" Can Load Error be detected and handled somehow?

Tags: android, eclipse, error-handling, widget

Sometimes my Widget/widgetProvider turns into a flat toast message "Problem Loading Widget" on the home screen does not even say which Widget.  What should be done in code to handle this error and remedy it.  I don't want to leave the widget sitting in this state.  Thanks

PS for those looking for a reason why this is happening its often a resource and not necessary an error in LogCat. Sometimes its expressed as a Warning.  I warning seems like an understatement for what has happened to the Widget however.

The question is when can this happen and how can one handle it when it does?  Is there an Intent broadcast about this and what could one to to recover?

Comment: Specifically could one request android to reload the widget

Comment: I used custom text view in my widget layout. That caused the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Check elements you used in the view. 
only 
FrameLayout,
LinearLayout,
RelativeLayout,
AnalogClock,
Button,
Chronometer,
ImageButton,
ImageView,
ProgressBar,
TextView,
ViewFlipper are allowed.

Comment: Hey Gangnus, What if we want to add some other element like EditText? Is it possible?

Comment: You could launch an activity from the widget. And in this activity you can use any element. You can also make this activity layout to look as if it is a part of the widget layout. Think - dou you really need to have an EditText always opened and ready to get symbols?

Comment: look http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html - for new android there are some new possibilities

Comment: Is that mean custom views are not allowed?

Comment: @DavidDimalanta That means that you can customize only components (views included) allowed for use in Widget.